# Expected path to Sluggable builder in Symfony/Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, slug

The default string normalization (provided by the `Doctrine_Inflector::urlize()` "sluggifier") isn't suitable for my project, so I need to utilize my own algorithm.

I set my schema up as follows:

```
MyObject:
  actAs:
    Sluggable:
      fields: [name]
      builder: array('TextUtility', 'normalize')
  columns:
    name: string(255)
```

And I added my utility class to the lib folder of my project (although I also tried the lib folder of an app) according to some instructions I found in another forum:

```
<?php
//lib/TextUtility.class.php

class TextUtility {
    public static function normalize($str) {
        /* ... */

        return $str;
    }
}
?>
```

When I run `symfony doctrine:build --all` I'm greeted by the following error:

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'array('TextUtility', 'normalize')' not found or invalid function name in /symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Template/Listener/Sluggable.php on line 171
```

I assume I'm just putting my utility in the wrong place and it's not being loaded when needed. Am I putting it in the wrong place? [Doctrine's documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_0/en/behaviors%3acore-behaviors%3asluggable) doesn't seem to mention the subject, unless I'm just looking at the wrong page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

arrays in YAML are defined other way:

```
MyObject:
  actAs:
    Sluggable:
      builder: [TextUtility, normalize]
```

Comment: Wow, as obvious as this is, I can't believe I missed it. Thanks!